# Can I write an iOS app that supports hotword detection like Siri?

Tags: ios, google-assistant-sdk, siri

Does apple allow you to write an iOS 14 app, that behaves like Siri, i.e. when a trigger word is spoken, (even when the iPhone is locked), the said app "is invoked" and does someting?

I'm writing this for my own use, so root the device, or run it in developer mode (if there is such thing), cripple Siri, are all acceptable.

Hey Siri, Ok Google is too long

Answer (score 0):

You can try recognition [Apple Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) + recording [AVAudioEngine](https://medium.com/@arvindhsukumar/using-avaudioengine-to-record-compress-and-stream-audio-on-ios-48dfee09fde4)

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly, there are even some ways to "bypass" siri, you can install Google Assistant for example and tell to siri "ok google" and it opens google, also alexa works very similar